# Unable to download Symfony2 from Git

Tags: git, symfony

I am trying to install Symfony2 on my Windows 7 machine. I have already installed XAMPP on it. I have executed the following command:

```
c:\xampp\php\pear\PHP\CodeSniffer\Standards>git clonegit://github.com/opensky/Symfony2-coding-standard.git Symfony2
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Cloning into 'Symfony2'...
fatal: remote error:
  Repository not found.
```

I am not sure whether this URL is right or not. I am new to Symfony.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very straightforward tutorial on how to set up your own Symfony project: http://symfony.com/download

I will not copy the tutorial, just mention two points:

1. To install and upgrade Symfony, you will have to use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/). (Details in the tutorial.)
2. Symfony code is actually [hosted on Github](https://github.com/symfony/), but those are only some of the components. The Symfony framework is a collection of libraries, some developed by the Symfony project itself, and some developed by third party projects (Doctrine probably being the most notable).

Have fun using Symfony. It may not be easy in the beginning, but you'll love it after a couple of weeks. Be sure to read the [Book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html) and the [Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/index.html) thoroughly, this will dramatically increase the fun.

Comment: Installing Symfony is the most difficult proposition I have ever undertaken. Each blog and each book I have read gives totally different protocols. Each one discusses so many softwares ranging from pear, curl, git, composer, xampp, php and finally Symfony! The symphony's website is the most terrible of all. I clicked the "Download" button, and nothing happens, Very very frustrating to install just one software!!

Comment: @user2649495 That may be difficult to believe, but the Symfony documentation is one of the best documentation i've read on a `PHP Framework`. There are several ways to install it but the simplest one is to follow the instruction mentioned here. For your info, Composer is just a package manager that considerably simplifies the process. I suggest you to install it by following the instructions

Answer (score -1):

install composer in your machine and try this for the latest version of sf2:

```
$ composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition path/ "2.5.*"
```

or, if you prefer the stable version, try this:

```
$ composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition path/ "2.3.*"
```

Comment: Thanks. I am very confused about so many commands. Can you please explain why composer is needed and what the above commands do. I am a newbee to PhP and I am totally lost :(

Comment: @user2649495 composer is a package manager for you php libs (see the Joël Salamin comment). How to install composer [here](http://culttt.com/2013/01/07/what-is-php-composer/)

Answer (score -2):

Check here and you'll see no Symfony projects listed here.  It was probably taken down - https://github.com/opensky/

A bunch of people seem to have created a bunch of forks though https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=symfony+2+coding+standard&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  You say you want to download Symfony but instead show a link to a Symfony coding standard.  Because your question is unclear, I can't proceed to answer.  Also, I provided a search link for you to browse.  Any one of those search results will give you a link that you can use to download the coding standard.

Comment: OpenSky has nothing to do with Symfony (except that they apparently use Symfony).

Comment: I understand that, but the asker had a link to an OpenSky repository and that's why I was confused by his question.

Comment: @user2910265: Yes, but the question is about installing Symfony2. Apparently the asker thought that the OpenSky repository contained the Symfony2 project. He even mentioned that the URL might be wrong.

Comment: I am essentially following the guidelines given at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7DtqO_7bn8